# module 'numba.findlib' has no attribute 'get_lib_dir'

Tags: python, anaconda, numba

I'm trying to learn how to use pyculib and got AttributeError: module 'numba.findlib' has no attribute 'get_lib_dir'

4 core CPU (intel) + GeForce GTX 745

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('C:/Python/Scripts/LearnCUDA/curand.py', wdir='C:/Python/Scripts/LearnCUDA')

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Python/Scripts/LearnCUDA/curand.py", line 11, in 
    from pyculib import rand as curand

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyculib__init__.py", line 49, in 
    from . import blas, sparse, fft, rand, sorting

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyculib\sorting__init__.py", line 1, in 
    from .radixsort import RadixSort

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyculib\sorting\radixsort.py", line 38, in 
    lib = load_lib('radixsort')

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyculib\sorting\common.py", line 24, in load_lib
    libpath = os.path.join(findlib.get_lib_dir(), fullname)

AttributeError: module 'numba.findlib' has no attribute 'get_lib_dir'

```
import numpy as np
from pyculib import rand as curand

prng = curand.PRNG(rndtype=curand.PRNG.XORWOW)
rand = np.empty(100000)
prng.uniform(rand)
print(rand[:10])
```

Comment: What is your version of cudatoolkit and cuda

Comment: Now I tried to reinstall them and got the following:

Comment: for cuda: PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: cuda

Comment: And for cudatoolkit: # All requested packages already installed.

Comment: after running numba -s I've got:: cudatoolkit   9.0 1 and cudnn 7.3.1  cuda9.0_0

Comment: Also just in case it would help  :W-10-10.0.17134-SP0  Python : MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64) Cpython 3.6.6 CUDA b'GeForce GTX 745' compute cap: 5 pci device id: 0 pci bus id: 1  CUDA driver : 7050  CUDA libraries: cublas, cusparse, cufft, curand, nvvm --- all open... ok

Comment: @Duck_dragon cudatoolkit 9.0 1 and cudnn 7.3.1 cuda9.0_0

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to `C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyculib\sorting\` and make a back up of common.py. Replace the code in common.py with

```
from numba import findlib
import ctypes
import os
import platform
import warnings

def library_extension():
    p = platform.system()
    if p == 'Linux':
        return 'so'
    if p == 'Windows':
        return 'dll'
    if p == 'Darwin':
        return 'dylib'

def load_lib(libname):
    fullname = 'pyculib_%s.%s' % (libname, library_extension())
    devlib = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), fullname)
    if os.path.exists(devlib):
        libpath = devlib
        warnings.warn('Using in-tree library %s' % libpath)
    else:
        libpath = os.path.join(findlib.get_lib_dirs()[0], fullname)

    return ctypes.CDLL(libpath)
```

If this dosent fix the problem revert to your backup

Comment: Thanks. I checked the common.py in my system and it differs from your code only in first line:  from __future__ import print_function, absolute_import, division

Comment: When I commented out the line, I've got the same: module 'numba.findlib' has no attribute 'get_lib_dir'

Comment: BTW, when I copy common.py into Spyder as findlib.py and run it doesn't complain. But when I commented out the 1-st line I've got: [autoreload of pyculib.sorting.common failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 244, in check
    superreload(m, reload, self.old_objects)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 378, in superreload
    module = reload(module)

Comment: File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 315, in reload
    return importlib.reload(module)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 159, in reload
    name=parent_name) from None
ImportError: parent 'pyculib.sorting' not in sys.modules
]

Comment: It was the line `libpath = os.path.join(findlib.get_lib_dir()[0], fullname)` that was wrong for me. `findlib.get_lig_dir()` does not exist. but `findlib.get_lib_dirs()` does but it returns a list. the `[0]` gets the string of the first item in that list. That's the only thing I changed on my end.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps solved the problem for me:

1. Download anaconda 3-5.1.0
2. Install numpy using `conda install numpy=1.13.0`
3. Install cudatoolkit 7.5 using `conda install cudatoolkit=7.5`
4. Install pyculib.
   If it works then every thing is ok, if you have an error like `CURAND_STATUS_LAUNCH_FAILURE` when using Anaconda Accelerate on GTX 1060
   you can then:
5. Install cudatoolkit=8.0 using `conda install -c numba cudatoolkit=8.0`