# Pyculib ImportError: cannot import name config

Tags: python, numba

when trying to import pyculib I get ImportError: cannot import name config

I have tried pip installing and conda installing various versions of the cudatoolkit but none seem to work.

```py
import pyculib
```

I get this error the first time I try to import pyculib

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/andillio/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyculib/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from . import blas, sparse, fft, rand, sorting
  File "/home/andillio/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyculib/sorting/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .radixsort import RadixSort
  File "/home/andillio/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyculib/sorting/radixsort.py", line 38, in <module>
    lib = load_lib('radixsort')
  File "/home/andillio/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyculib/sorting/common.py", line 24, in load_lib
    libpath = os.path.join(findlib.get_lib_dir(), fullname)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_lib_dir'
```

and this error if I try a second time

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named config
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [module 'numba.findlib' has no attribute 'get\_lib\_dir'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55579082/module-numba-findlib-has-no-attribute-get-lib-dir)

Comment: You're going to find that pyculib is no longer maintained. You might want to switch to cupy.  Pyculib stopped maintenance it seems in the CUDA 8 timeframe.  However numba has proceeded beyond that, so pyculib is no longer in sync with the current numba, which is why this issue is popping up. A possible fix is in the answer given by officereso [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55579082/module-numba-findlib-has-no-attribute-get-lib-dir) - modification of a specific `common.py` file. You will also probably find incompatibilities with newer CUDA libraries, so use CUDA 8 in your conda env.